# Does a JSON-RPC server exist for answering general Prolog queries?

Tags: json, rpc, swi-prolog

I saw this [tutorial](http://technogems.blogspot.com/2011/08/easy-cross-platform-inter-process.html) for writing a JSON-RPC server for SWI-Prolog.  Unfortunately, all it does is add two numbers.  I'm wondering if there exists a RPC server for SWI-Prolog that can define new rules and answer general Prolog queries, returning JSON lists, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a tour on [SWI-Prolog website](http://www.swi-prolog.org/), proudly self-powered, you can see at work some of the features offered by [http package](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/http.html).

It's a fairly large range of tools, and to grasp the basic of the system, the easiest way it's to follow the specific [How to](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/) section, step by step. There is a small bug you should be aware in the [LOD Crawler](http://www.swi-prolog.org/howto/http/HTMLStyle.html): add  an option on line 42 of lod.pl:

```
...
    ;   rdf_load(URI2, [format(xml)]),
....
```

or you will probably get

> Internal server error
>
> Domain error: `content_type' expected, found` text/xml;charset=UTF-8'

when running the sample.

An important feature of the IDE it's the ability to debug the HTTP requests.

When done with the HowTo, you can take a look to [Cliopatria](http://cliopatria.swi-prolog.org/home), dedicated to interfacing RDF to HTML. It come with a `pirates demo`, I must say I find it a bit too 'crude' for my taste, and I don't know about YUI, used in the award winning [MultimediaN](http://e-culture.multimedian.nl/software/ClioPatria.shtml) project. Then I've used [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to gain a modern look for the front end, with appreciable result (I'm sorry I can't - yet - publish it, need more time to engineering the system).

HTH

Comment: I tried out Cliopatria, but I found that the user interface only allowed SPARQL and SeRQL queries.  I couldn't figure out how to issue Prolog queries and define new rules.

Comment: Prolog queries are implicitly used when responding to http requests: see library(http/http_parameter) and http_handler. Basic usage is well covered by the How To 'demo'